# How do I select an item in a datagridview

Tags: c#

I've done this in the past with VB.Net I'm just not sure how to do this in C#. Below is the code that I would use in VB

```
private void LabelsGV_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                Int32 i, j;

                i = LabelsGV.CurrentRow.Index;
                Key = LabelsGV.Item(0, i).Value;

            }
```

it's pretty straight forward, in the LabelsGV.Item 0 represents the column and i represents the row. Unfortunately Item doesn't work in C# so it looks like I need an alternative or I need to code it differently.

The answer is `Key = (String)LabelsGV[0, i].Value;` 
Thank You everyone for your help.

Comment: Um, C# and VB are different?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. You can also find out more about current [DataGridView usage Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Key = LabelsGV[0, i].Value;
```

OR

```
Key = LabelsGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
```

OR

```
Key = LabelsGV.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: Then please accept the @Jeffrey's answer. This is how this website works.

Answer (score 0):

look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

there are two properties:
rowIndex, columnIndex.